# Como restringir tipos herdados a partir de um nível de hierarquia?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos

Dado o modelo hipotético abaixo:

```
public abstract class Veiculo
{
    public Motor Motor { get; set; }
}

public class Aviao : Veiculo { }

public abstract class Motor { }

public class MotorCarro : Motor { }

public class MotorAviao : Motor { }
```

É possível restringir o tipo de `Motor` para a classe `Aviao` como sendo apenas `MotorAviao` e seus derivados? Ou ainda, qual seria a melhor solução para esse cenário?

### Edit

O mesmo cenário, mas com um atributo que é bem comum pra casos de agregação: uma lista de todos objetos agregados do outro lado do relacionamento.

A classe `Motor` deveria conhecer todos veículos que a utilizam. Ficaria assim:

```
public abstract class Motor
{
    public virtual ICollection<Veiculo> Veiculos { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Isso e' bem diferente da pergunta original - acho que o correcto seria abrir uma segunda pergunta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O modo mais comum de resolver este tipo de problemas e' tornar a class base generica, e deixar a class derivada escolher o seu tipo de motor.

```
public abstract class Veiculo<TMotor> where TMotor : Motor
{
    public TMotor Motor { get; set; }
}

//aviao = veiculo com motor de aviao
public class Aviao : Veiculo<MotorAviao> { }

public class Carro : Veiculo<MotorCarro> { }
```